# Ubuntu 18.10 no scaling settings

Tags: gnome, hdpi, 18.10

I’ve just installed 18.10, and have no scaling settings availble in setting applet somehow. I’ve set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor to {‘eDP-1’: 16} in donf-editor and it’ve scaled the login screen but does nothing for the desktop itself. I’ve also tried to play with all other “scale-...” setting in dconf with no success. The only thing worked was xsettings.overrides but it scales only windows, not dash/menu etc.
So wheres the good’old scale setting in ubuntu 18.10?

Comment: Ok, the solution was to set scalong in .config/monitors.xml

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.10, and scale of  percent 100 / 200 / 300 / 400 are there on Devices Displays using native drivers.  200% works for me.

What's lacking is per-monitor scale setting and fractional (I want 140%, not 200%).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Tweaks** -> **Fonts** and there is option **Scaling Factor**.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem as you can see here https://imgur.com/a/KQNXNFE it only increases the font size and not the overall zoom. Valid (i.e. without pixelization) fractional zoom is a MUST feature still missing in Gnome 3.30.1 (Ubuntu 18.10)

Comment: Just set it in ~/.config/monitors.xml like this: <scale>2</scale> Also you have to copy it into /var/lib/gdm3 or something for gdm scale/rotation (though gdm seems to scale by itself somehow)

Comment: How do you get to tweaks in 18.10? I'm on the live USB boot, and apt install gnome-tweak-tools is no longer installable?

Comment: Go to Ubuntu Software and type tweaks or GNOME Tweaks